# The 'chruby' command can't be found

Tags: ruby, flutter, macos, chruby

I'm using Hackintosh on my HP laptop to run flutter apps on the iOS simulator. Everything was fine until I got an error saying that I need to update cocoa pods. When I tried to do so, it said that I don't have write permissions for the 'ruby'. Upon googling this error, I run these commands:
`brew install chruby ruby-install`
`ruby-install ruby`
They run successfully but I got theses warning messages:
[image]
I added the paths to .zshrc file as shown:
[image]
When I tried to run the command `chruby 3.2.2` to switch to ruby version 3.2.2, which has been installed, it said that the 'chruby' command isn't recognized.

I tried to add the paths to the .bash_profile file, but I couldn't find it in the hidden files.

Comment: You didn’t follow the directions given. It says to add the lines with the `source …` commands to your `.zshrc`, not to update your `PATH` variable with the .sh files referenced.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: There's no warning messages; those are informational. `.bash_profile` isn't `.zshrc`; which shell are you running? Did you relaunch the terminal (or source the shell init script, or run the commands in the existing terminal)?

Comment: OOT. I don't get why you can't put images instead of texts for simple shell scripting like this. In fact, IMHO it is better for it to be images. It's not as if you need to copy-paste the homebrew line. It's not some javascript or C coding error that you need to try it yourself. It's just a one line brew installation. Don't tell me you want a screen reader to read all those homebrew prints with all the installation processes and errors.

Comment: same here.. did you find solution?

Comment: @FahimParkar Unfortunately no